# Appending a sub-menu under an existing sub-menu in Blender 2.8

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I can add menus to Blender 2.8 with the python code below but how can I add a sub-menu using python to one of Blenders existing menus?  I'm trying to add the rtMyMenu sub-menu under Blenders **Add-Curve** sub-menu (**see red arrow**).

What I currently have is:

```
-Add-
-rtMyMenu-  -rtMyOperator-
```

What I'm trying to get is:

```
-Add-
-Curve-
      -rtMyMenu-  -rtMyOperator-
```

-

```
import bpy

class OBJECT_OT_myoperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = 'object.myoperator'
    bl_label = 'rtMyOperator'
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        # ...affairs...
        return {'FINISHED'}

class OBJECT_MT_mymenu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_idname = 'object.mymenu'
    bl_label = 'rtMyMenu'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.operator(OBJECT_OT_myoperator.bl_idname)

def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.menu(OBJECT_MT_mymenu.bl_idname)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_myoperator)
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_MT_mymenu)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_add.append(menu_func)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_OT_myooperator)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_MT_mymenu)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_add.remove(menu_func)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

I tried

```
bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_add_curve.append(menu_func)
```

and

```
bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_add_curve.remove(menu_func)
```

But that doesn't work.

[image: submenus]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Minor issue: `VIEW3D_MT_add_curve` doesn't exist, you have to append to `VIEW3D_MT_curve_add` rather. Further reading: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Menu.html

[image]

```
import bpy

class MY_MT_CustomMenu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "First Menu"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_MT_custom_menu"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label(text="Hello First Menu!", icon='WORLD_DATA')

         # call the second custom menu
        layout.menu("OBJECT_MT_sub_menu", icon="COLLAPSEMENU")


class MY_MT_CustomSubMenu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "Sub Menu"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_MT_sub_menu"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label(text="Hello Second Menu!", icon='WORLD_DATA')

        # call another predefined menu
        layout.operator("wm.call_menu", text="Unwrap").name = "VIEW3D_MT_uv_map" 


def draw_menu(self, context):
    self.layout.menu(MY_MT_CustomMenu.bl_idname)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MY_MT_CustomMenu)
    bpy.utils.register_class(MY_MT_CustomSubMenu)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_curve_add.append(draw_menu)

def unregister():
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_curve_add.remove(draw_menu)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MY_MT_CustomSubMenu)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MY_MT_CustomMenu)    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Based on: [How to create a custom UI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57332/31447) and [Python: Extend “Select Similar” menu?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/56830/31447)

Comment: Thanks! That was a more clear example than I could find in the docs.

Comment: Yep, barely documented. For UI stuff, read [How to create a custom UI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57306/how-to-create-a-custom-ui/57332#57332). Cheers @JonathanL