# Adding entry in existing menu

Tags: python, scripting, interface

This is my first post. I am new to scripting and I'm facing the overwhelming information of the api, python, etc.
I just want to know if it is possible to add a new entry on the file menu of blender or in any other of the header

[image: file menu enytry]

Comment: Without overriding the actual draw method that's not possible at the moment. However, supported is to *append* or *prepend* a new item to existing menus, meaning adding a new item at the top of the whole menu (YOUR_ITEM, New, Open, Open Re...) or appending your item to the bottom of the menu (Defaults, Quit, YOUR_ITEM). See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3403/31447

Comment: Ok i understand that, will be great to add in top of the new section, if is not too much to ask, how can i achieve that? the link you post is from older blender, that will work on new versions? thanx in advance

Comment: Doesn't matter, still the same. A demo: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/152566/31447 Just replace `VIEW3D_MT_curve_add` with `TOPBAR_MT_file` to add a new item to the file menu. Instead of calling `append(draw_menu)`, use `prepend()` https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Menu.html?highlight=prepend#extending-menus